# Install Dual Boot fail: Ubuntu cannot find Windows 7

Tags: dual-boot

I need to install Ubuntu as dual boot option on a HP Z800 Workstation which has Windows 7 installed. 
Ubuntu installer cannot detect Windows and complains "This computer currently has no detected operating systems". 
I tried to allocated a partition of 200GB of free space using Windows disk manager, and the Ubuntu installer fails to see any free space.
The PC features: 24Gb of RAM, dual Xeon CPU, 2TB of disk space. 
Does anyone know what's going on?
[Windows Disk Partition image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWoKK.jpg)
[UBUNTU did not find Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFZhd.jpg)

Comment: will you please add screen shot of your partition table?--

Comment: Ravan, I just added links to the partition images captured

Comment: Is it gpt?...to know: open command prompt--> type `diskpart` -->enter-->type `list disk`...please add output to Q

Answer (score 0):

Do you know, if the hard disk uses a GPT or a MBR structure? If it is GPT, there should be also a corresponding fake MBR. Maybe these two are not consistent.

Some time ago, I had a similar problem. The Ubuntu installer could not detect the fresh Windows 7 installation. I solved it by wiping the first sectors of my hard disk. Then I could create a clean MBR structure and install Windows and Ubuntu again. Before you continue with any experimental steps, you should create a complete backup of your Windows installation.